# Why wordpress don't see the archive-product page?

Tags: woocommerce

I installed my theme with just html, and woocommerce plugin. 
I created in my theme directory woocommerce and inside a file archive-products.
In admin, in settings -> reading i choose as a static page the Shop.

But i saw just the page, not the archive-product page. 
Where i done a mistake?

Comment: What do you mean "installed with just html". A theme is more than just html. Do you have any code or a functional example.

Comment: I mean, i create the theme with underscores.me. 
Before that i move the theme from the figma to html, css. 

But, i forgot to add check button for underscores for woocommerce, and i think that may be the problem. 

Because, when i activate the theme twenty... , the home page is archive-product.

Answer (score 0):

When i create a theme with underscores.me, i forgot to check a checkbox for woocommerce.

Now i create another theme with checked checkbox, and the theme work.